# How to get Reddit submission by fullname using Redd gem?

Tags: ruby, reddit

I'm trying to get submission by fullname using Redd gem (https://github.com/avinashbot/redd):

```
r = Redd.it(:userless, 'client_id', 'secret_id', user_agent: 'comment streamer')
r.from_fullname('t3_52jtld')
```

But get error:

`NameError: uninitialized constant Redd::Response::ParseJson::JSONError`

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `r.authorize!` before `r.from_fullname`